# Get a list of entities in an order and in multiple copies from a room database

Tags: android, android-room

I want to create an android studio application to manage sports sessions. For that I imagine a model with two entities. First the Training entity and the Exercise entity. The idea is that the Training entity gives access to a list of Exercises that compose the training program.

I would like that in my DAO there is a method which could take a Training id in parameters and return the list of associated exercise in the right order.
For example, if I create a Training named training_1 with the sequence of the exercises: exercise_1, exercise_3, exercise_1 and exercise_2
The DAO would have a method getTrainingProgram which will return the list:
[exercise_1, exercise_3, exercise_1 and exercise_2]
by passing the id of training_1 in parameters.

The difficulty here is to be able to return the Exercise list whit a predefined order and with some Exercises that could be present several times.

I tried to do that with the following way:
As this is a many to many association between the Trainings and the Exercises, I created the entity TrainingExerciseMappingTable to bind them.
This entity contains the id of a Training, the id of an Exercise and the index of this Exercise in the Training as an int. So I can query the Exercises of the Training ordered by this index parameter. Also, the entries of TrainingExerciseMappingTable have their own id (a UUID randomly generated), because a training could contain many times the same Exercise, so the trainingId and exerciceId cannot be the only primary keys.

To visualize it, here is my model in UML:

[image]

I created all the Entities and the DAO, but the method getTrainingProgram does not work, it always returns an empty list. Actually, I’m new to android studio and I’m not sure that's the right approach. I will be very grateful if an expert could help me to make this method getExercisesByTraining works as I expect or even give me a better way to achieve that.

Here are my entities and the DAO of my application, I access the database with Room and ksp.

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Training(
    val title: String,
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID)
    val trainingId: String = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes((title).toByteArray()).toString()
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Exercise(
    val name: String,
    val time: Long,
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID)
    val exerciseId: String = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes((name + time).toByteArray()).toString()
)
```

```kotlin
data class TrainingWithExerciseList(
    @Embedded
    val training: Training,
    @Relation(
        entity = Exercise::class,
        parentColumn = ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID,
        entityColumn = ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID,
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = TrainingExerciseMappingTable::class,
            parentColumn = ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID_REF,
            entityColumn = ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID_REF
        )
    )
    val exerciseList: List<Exercise>
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = [ModelConstants.TRAINING_EXERCISE_MAPPING_ID, ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID_REF, ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID_REF],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Training::class,
            parentColumns = [ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID],
            childColumns = [ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID_REF],
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Exercise::class,
            parentColumns = [ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID],
            childColumns = [ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID_REF],
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class TrainingExerciseMappingTable(
    val trainingIdRef: String,
    val exerciseIdRef: String,
    val indexExercise: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true, name = ModelConstants.TRAINING_EXERCISE_MAPPING_ID)
    val trainingExerciseMappingId: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
)
```

```kotlin
@Dao
interface CustomTrainingDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT t.* " +
            "FROM Training t " +
            "INNER JOIN TrainingExerciseMappingTable stmt ON t.trainingId = stmt.trainingIdRef " +
            "WHERE stmt.trainingIdRef = :trainingIdSelected " +
            "ORDER BY stmt.indexExercise ASC")
}
fun getTrainingProgram(trainingIdSelected: String): List<TrainingWithExerciseList>
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `@Embedded .... @Relation` Room uses ONLY the parents (@Embedded) that are extracted by the source query. The children, ALWAYS ALL CHILDREN, per parent are obtaining by an underlying query that is built by room.

As such, to order by the indexExercise column, you need to bypass Room's convenience (basic/simple) handling.

As you may, at times, want the indexExercise value then consider this additional  POJO:-

```
data class MappedTrainingExerciseWithMappedExercise(
    @Embedded
    val trainingExerciseMappingTable: TrainingExerciseMappingTable,
    @Relation(
        entity = Exercise::class,
        entityColumn = ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID,
        parentColumn = ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID_REF
    )
    val exercise: Exercise
)
```

- this will be used to retrieve a single mapping with the mapped exercise

However, still the issue with bypassing the convenience handling has not bee addressed. To facilitate this consider the following 2 new Querys (in `CustomTrainingDao`):-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM training WHERE ${ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID}=:trainingId")
fun getTrainingById(trainingId: String): Training

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM TrainingExerciseMappingTable WHERE ${ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID_REF}=:trainingId ORDER BY indexExercise ASC")
fun getMappedTrainingExerciseWithMap(trainingId: String): List<MappedTrainingExerciseWithMappedExercise>
```

Finally to bypass Room's handling the following:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun getTrainingProgram(trainingIdSelected: String): TrainingWithExerciseList {
    val training = getTrainingById(trainingIdSelected)
    val trainingExerciseWithMappedExercise = getMappedTrainingExerciseWithMap(trainingIdSelected)
    val exercises = arrayListOf<Exercise>()
    for (tewme in trainingExerciseWithMappedExercise) {
        exercises.add(tewme.exercise)
    }
    return TrainingWithExerciseList(training,exercises)
}
```

So this retrieves the respective Training along with the respective list of the `MappedTrainingExerciseWithMappedExercise`'s (POJO above) but then builds and returns the original required TrainingWithExerciseList.

**Demo**

Using the above *(note replacing the original `getTrainingProgram` function with the above)*, a suitable `@Database` annotated task (note allowing the use of the Main thread, for convenience/brevity), and the following activity code:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: CustomTrainingDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getCustomTrainingDao()

        val t1id = "T1ID"
        dao.insert(Training("T1",t1id))
        val t2id = "T2ID"
        dao.insert(Training("T2",t2id))
        val t3id = "T3ID"
        dao.insert(Training("T3",t3id))

        val e1id = "E1ID"
        dao.insert(Exercise("EX001",100,e1id))
        val e2id = "E2ID"
        dao.insert(Exercise("EX02",200,e2id))
        val e3Id = "E3ID"
        dao.insert(Exercise("EX03",300,e3Id))
        val e4id = "E4ID"
        dao.insert(Exercise("EX04",400,e4id))

        dao.insert(TrainingExerciseMappingTable(t1id,e2id,10))
        dao.insert(TrainingExerciseMappingTable(t1id,e4id,5))
        dao.insert(TrainingExerciseMappingTable(t1id,e1id,99))
        dao.insert(TrainingExerciseMappingTable(t1id,e1id,7))

        dao.insert(TrainingExerciseMappingTable(t3id,e1id,25))
        dao.insert(TrainingExerciseMappingTable(t3id,e4id,1))
        dao.insert(TrainingExerciseMappingTable(t3id,e3Id,10))
        dao.insert(TrainingExerciseMappingTable(t3id,e2id,75))

        logTrainingProgram(dao.getTrainingProgram(t1id),"TP 001")
        logTrainingProgram(dao.getTrainingProgram(t2id),"TP 002")
        logTrainingProgram(dao.getTrainingProgram(t3id),"TP 003")

    }

    fun logTrainingProgram(tp: TrainingWithExerciseList,tagSuffix: String) {
        Log.d("DBINFO_${tagSuffix}","Starting Logging for ${tagSuffix}")
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (el in tp.exerciseList) {
            sb.append("\n\tExercise is ${el.name} Duration is ${el.time} ID is ${el.exerciseId}")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO_${tagSuffix}","Training Program: Title = ${tp.training.title} ID is ${tp.training.trainingId}. It has ${tp.exerciseList.size} exercises: They are:-${sb}")
    }
}
```

When run (only designed to run once) then the log includes:-

```
2023-10-30 07:59:10.378 D/DBINFO_TP 001: Starting Logging for TP 001
2023-10-30 07:59:10.378 D/DBINFO_TP 001: Training Program: Title = T1 ID is T1ID. It has 4 exercises: They are:-
        Exercise is EX04 Duration is 400 ID is E4ID
        Exercise is EX001 Duration is 100 ID is E1ID
        Exercise is EX02 Duration is 200 ID is E2ID
        Exercise is EX001 Duration is 100 ID is E1ID
        
        
2023-10-30 07:59:10.384 D/DBINFO_TP 002: Starting Logging for TP 002
2023-10-30 07:59:10.384 D/DBINFO_TP 002: Training Program: Title = T2 ID is T2ID. It has 0 exercises: They are:-


2023-10-30 07:59:10.390 D/DBINFO_TP 003: Starting Logging for TP 003
2023-10-30 07:59:10.390 D/DBINFO_TP 003: Training Program: Title = T3 ID is T3ID. It has 4 exercises: They are:-
        Exercise is EX04 Duration is 400 ID is E4ID
        Exercise is EX03 Duration is 300 ID is E3ID
        Exercise is EX001 Duration is 100 ID is E1ID
        Exercise is EX02 Duration is 200 ID is E2ID
```

As can be seen the order is as expected AND for T1 EX001 has appeared twice and appropriately ordered.

- i.e. for T1

  - EX04 is 1st (ix = 5),
  - EX001 is 2nd (ix = 7),
  - EX02 is 3rd (ix = 10),
  - and the other EX001 is 4th (ix = 99)

---

**Additional**

---

In regard to:-

> Also, the entries of TrainingExerciseMappingTable have their own id (a UUID randomly generated), because a training could contain many times the same Exercise, so the trainingId and exerciceId cannot be the only primary keys.

Rather than the storage wise relatively expensive use of a UUID simply to allow the mapping of the same exercise/training. A more efficient way could be to make what was the UUID an integer type (thus a maximum of 8 bytes storage) and have it as the primary key, thus a generated value, in conjunction with a NON-UNIQUE index on the 2 mapping columns.

e.g.

```
@Entity(
    indices = [
        Index(ModelConstants.TRAINING_EXERCISE_MAPPING_ID, ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID_REF)
              ],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Training::class,
            parentColumns = [ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID],
            childColumns = [ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID_REF],
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Exercise::class,
            parentColumns = [ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID],
            childColumns = [ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID_REF],
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class TrainingExerciseMappingTable(
    @ColumnInfo(name = ModelConstants.TRAINING_ID_REF)
    val trainingIdRef: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ModelConstants.EXERCISE_ID_REF, index = true)
    val exerciseIdRef: String,
    val indexExercise: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = ModelConstants.TRAINING_EXERCISE_MAPPING_ID)
    @PrimaryKey
    val trainingExerciseMappingId: Long?=null
)
```

- note the use of `Long?=null` to accommodate how Room handles a Primary Key that does not have the wasteful `autoGenerate = true`.

Making just the changes to the TrainingExerciseMappingTable (i.e. an index on only the 2 mapping columns and the single primary key). When used returns exactly the same results.

However the stored data, as per App Inspection is:-

[image]

- in this case the storage for the `training_exercise_mapping_id` column is 1 byte per row, as SQLite will store the value as efficiently as it can.

As opposed to the use of the UUDI which would be like:-

[image]

- i.e. at least 36 bytes for the `training_exercise_mapping_id`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for my late response. Actually, I've been able to test that it works well, but I'm still struggling to understand how it can work. I don't understand how the method getMappedTrainingExerciseWithMap can return the right list of MappedTrainingExerciseWithMappedExercise from the table TrainingExerciseMappingTable. I don't know how Room handle it to make the underlying association. Otherwise, your answer is very well detailed, you must have spent some time on it and I thank you very much.

Comment: @Thibaut_Esteve the crux of the solution is that when getting the mapped exercises the **TrainingExerciseMappingTable** is the source and therefore can be sorted according to the `indexExercise` column (note that the Training object is first obtained from the Training table). The two are finally combined when returning the `TrainingWithExerciseList `.